# Send request failed { code: -32602, message: 'invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Hash' }

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, string

I am new to ethereum and deploying my first contract with simple method getting following error:

```
[2018-03-24 11:08:14.364] [ERROR] ipcProviderBackend - Send request failed { code: -32602,
  message: 'invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Hash' }
```

Following is the contract method in solidity that i am calling:

```
function testContract(string title,string _description,
                           address _contractAddressOfAsset,
                           string _recordIdOfAsset,
                           uint _deadline,
                           uint _startingPrice,
                           uint _reservePrice,
                           uint _distributionCut,
                           address _distributionCutAddress) public returns (bool k) {


        test=title;
        return true;
    }
```

Here ,
test is the global variable of type string.

Note: I have deployed this contract in the private network and  this contract from the mist browser

Following are the version details of geth:

```
Geth
Version: 1.7.3-stable
Git Commit: 4bb3c89d44e372e6a9ab85a8be0c9345265c763a
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.9
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.9
```

Comment: Please add the cli args of the geth client

Comment: @cleanunicorn following are the arguments for geth cli:
 geth --networkid 200 --identity "node1" --verbosity 3 --rpc --rpcport 8081 --rpccorsdomain "*" --port 30303 --rpcapi "db,eth,net,personal,web3" --nat none --datadir=/test/datadir --unlock <accound address> --mine --ipcpath /test/datadir/geth.ipc

Comment: Are you passing values correctly? Proper ethereum address in address params. How are you calling this method? Remix? web3.js? geth console?

Comment: I am calling this using Mist browser

Comment: If you use Mist browser you should have the javascript code that calls the smart contract via web3. If so it would be great if you can post it.

Comment: I have deployed this contract using mist which provides a UI for executing contract which internally uses web3.So I dont have any javascript code for calling this contract

Comment: In Mist/EthereumWallet, did you put string and address parameters into ""?

Comment: No I have not quoted string or address parameters. I have pass them as is

Comment: When you are passing the Parameters make sure you pass it as exactly defined - String : "someString" - uint : 2 - address : "pass in address under the quotes" for instance - function testFunction(uint num, string someString, address someAddress){
} to call this function
testFunction(2, "randomString", "0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c") Hope it helps.